# Showing Tooltip of WPF control under the decrative touches

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a window with a number of controls upon it, each control with a Tooltip associated.  In an effort to jazz up the window a little, I have overlayed some semi-transparent ellipses which gives the whole window a glossy finish, however, in some cases the positioning of these ellipses are preventing the hit-test getting down to my controls.

How can I have the ellipses visible, but transparent from a hit-test point-of-view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsHitTestVisible = false

Comment: That's it... Expression Blend had collapsed it into the infrequently used properties and I didn't expand them all!  I knew it was something simple!